# Python - how to add a blank character to a string so as to add a column to a db

Tags: python, join, append

I am using SQLite3 and Python 2.7 atm.  I have run into a problem where I have a bunch of data with one string in my list could have up to 5 characters in it, but not necessarily - when putting this into my sql table, I need the 5 columns tho.  So I am trying to add "' " to the string so as to add the extra columns - thus far I have put in this:

```
while len(row[36].split(',')) < 5:
    row[36] = '%s%s'%(row[36],', ')
```

The error I get at this time is: `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment.`

If there is anything else needed, just let me know.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like the `row` variable is actually a tuple instead of a list.

Tuples are immutable. You'll need to convert `row` to a list first before you can change values in it:

`row = list(row)`

Or better still, when creating `row`, make it a list to begin with.